# Is “Do you be?” a grammatical and meaningful sentence in present-day English?

Tags: grammaticality, questions, copular-verbs, do-support

Suppose you were asked the question:

- Do you be?

I wonder what you would understand it to mean, and I wonder how you would answer it.

Comment: In what context would you ask it?

Comment: @KillingTime I read the sentence “…let Newton be…” Naturally I come up with “Does Newton be?” and then “do you be”. I am only curious about it, since it seems quite unnatural but seems not quite wrong.

Comment: You must be thinking of Pope's famous couplet "Nature and Nature's laws lay hid in night. God said 'Let Newton be!' and all was light". The sense here is "Allow Newton to exist" (Pope is implying that God created Sir Isaac Newton to explain the laws of physics to the world.) _Let [something] be_ is grammatical, but _does [something] be?_ is not.

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate after tidying up your question's formatting. If that doesn't answer your question, or if I have misunderstood you, please edit your question to make this clearer. Fully explaining all the nuts and bolts of [*do*-support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support) in English—whether for emphasis, negation, questions, or various other reasons—would probably be too large for our format here. Grammatical verbs like auxiliaries and copulae work differently compared with lexical verbs.

Comment: I just built my new robot.  To find out if I was successful,  I ask it, "Do you be?"

Comment: @GEdgar Not in English, you don't be asking that.